# infinitive :To and In order to

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitives

> 1.The fourth case is more diffuse – the forging of various bilateral links with the fishing industry: some ENGOs have succeeded in working with fishers ***to bring*** in environmental measures that they can accept.
>
> 2. They work with the lawyers ***to solve*** this issue.

Can the infinitive in the example sentences be understood as **in order to**?

Does the meaning change if the sentences are interpreted to be **in order to**?

Comment: Yes - in such contexts, ***to [verb]*** is equivalent to ***in order to [verb] / for the purpose of [verbing].*** So no - the meaning *wouldn't* change if you were to make such a substitution (and you *couldn't* apply a different "interpretation").

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the answer. For the first sentence, why can it be understood as in order to?  I thought the infinitive clause tells the result instead of the purpose.

Comment: "To solve this issue" is a purpose adjunct, and "in order to" can be added with no change of meaning: They work with the lawyers (in order) to solve this issue.

Comment: Kathy: - You've misunderstood the "significance" of the infinitive clause in such constructions. In and of itself, ***to [verb]*** here *always* conveys "purpose" - it's the preceding "primary" verb that might indicate whether that purpose was successfully achieved as a "result". Compare *They **managed** to kill him* (result = he was killed) and *They **tried** to kill him* (result = he *wasn't* killed; he survived).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you again, sorry my statement earlier was unclear. I mean in the first sentence, the infinitive clause tells the result instead of the purpose.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for the answer, how about the first example sentence?

Comment: It's just the same, i.e. a purpose adjunct: _some ENGOs have succeeded in working with fishers (in order) to bring in environmental measures that they can accept_.

Comment: @BillJ: But it seems to me there's at least some *hypothetical* ambiguity involved here. Pragmatically, the assumption isn't that what these ENGOs ***succeeded*** in doing was ***working with fishers*** (actual "fishermen"? top executives within the fishing industry?) ***in pursuit of the stated goal*** (which they may or may not ***ever*** achieve). Syntactically, that would seem to be the *default* interpretation, but pragmatically I think we can take it for granted the intended sense is that ***the goal was in fact achieved***.

Comment: Um, some of the cases of a verb followed by a to-infinitive aren't expressing purpose; some are catenative verbs. I'm pretty sure "**work with** someone **to...**" is expressing purpose, but "they **tried** to kill him", example, mentioned by @FumbleFingers, is *to try* as a catenative verb. *To ask*, *to attempt*, *to begin* are all catenative verbs that can take a to-infinitive as object.

Comment: @SamBC  The simple fact is that "(in order) to solve this issue" is a purpose adjunct. Catenative has nothing to do with it here, since "work" is not a catenative verb, and in any case there is an intervening PP between the verbs..

Comment: @BillJ I was referring to FumbleFingers' assertion that the to infinitive is always purposive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these examples, no change in meaning is made by substituting ***in order to*** in place of ***to***. That is not always the case.

Sometimes a to-infinitive is an adjunct that expresses purpose. The role is essentially equivalent to that of an adverbial of purposes using *in order to*. But sometimes it isn't.

Verbs like *to ask*, *to attempt*, *to consent*, *to swear*, *to decide*, *to threaten* - these are all ***catenative*** verbs, verbs that (can) take other verb expressions as objects. I might ask you *to be clearer*, or threaten *to flag your post*. There, the to-infinitive phrases are not modifying an otherwise complete verb, but rather they are defining precisely what the main verb means, just like any other object or complement. Some catenative verbs take a to-infinitive, some take a bare infinitive, and some take a gerund - and in all of those cases it may be an infinitive or gerund phrase, rather than just those verb forms.

Verbs can take a lot of things as objects, depending on the verb. Nouns and noun phrases are the usual objects, but we also get adjectival or verb phrases as complements, for certain verbs (such as linking verbs and catenative verbs, respectively). That's not what's happening in your examples, though.

In your examples, *work* is intransitive, and both the *with*-phrase and the infinitive phrase are acting as adverbials - one indicating the *who* and the other indicating the *why*. Infinitives can act as adverbials, though it's not a structure that people often think about in my experience. Thus, *in order to* would lead to the same meaning as *to*, though arguably it gives rise to a different structure - but only because they are different sorts of adverbial.

Comment: Thank you for the answers :) But why can the infinitive in the first example sentence be substituted by "in order to", I thought the infinitive clause in that sentence tells what was achieved instead of the purpose.

Comment: It says what the objective was; it doesn't say whether that objective was achieved. That might be implicit, or stated explicitly elsewhere. You might say "I worked with the client to resolve their problem, but I was not successful."

Comment: Sorry for asking again, I've been thinking about this sentence again and again, since the verb "succeeded" is placed in the sentence, can it be understood that "to bring in environmental measures which they can accept" is in fact achieved?

Comment: Yes, in this case it is stated explicitly elsewhere in the sentence. I mean, you could argue that it means they succeeded in working with them, not in achieving the goal, but that would be a perverse reading, in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again.What Is the understood subject of the infinitive "to bring in environmental measures that they can accept." ? Is it "some ENGOS" or "fishers"?

Comment: Nothing in the syntax tells you which it is - you have to work it out from the semantics. Who is bringing in the measures, and who is able to accept them? The first is ambiguous from this snippet of text; it could be the government or regulators, it could be the fishing industry itself. As to who is able to accept them, well, the ENGOs will accept most measures, so it must be the fishers whose acceptance is in question.